# null output when get data from github api using android

Tags: android, api, github, mvvm, retrofit

I'm using MVVM Design Pattern to build this app, but when I load data user using the searching method I get issue like this:

```
2020-05-04 11:34:55.839 11187-11187/com.planetmars23.im.movie_catalogue D/imam_log: null
2020-05-04 11:34:55.839 11187-11187/com.planetmars23.im.movie_catalogue I/imam_log: setSearchUserGithub - Response success
```

```
public void setSearchUserGithub(String accessToken, String user) {

        Call<UserDataObject> githubSearchObjectCall = service.userSearchResult(user);
        githubSearchObjectCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserDataObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserDataObject> call, Response<UserDataObject> response) {
                assert response.body() != null;
                listGithub.setValue(response.body().getResults());
                Log.d(Base.LOG, String.valueOf(response.body().getResults()));
                Log.i(Base.LOG, "setSearchUserGithub - Response success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserDataObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w(Base.LOG, "setSearchUserGithub - Response failed :" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm using this for GitHub service

```
    @GET("/search/users?")
    @Headers("Authorization:"+ Base.KEY)
    Call<UserDataObject> userSearchResult(@Query("q") String username);
```